# DFS for undirected Graphs whithout two searches

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

Good Morning,

I am a newbie in the graph world and I have some questions about DFS,  which  I haven't found in the other topics.

I took the DFS code  of the site:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/

( I took the Java implementation )

The graph  is built in the main function  :

```
    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    g.addEdge(1, 2);
    g.addEdge(2, 0);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);
    g.addEdge(3, 1);
    g.addEdge(2, 4);
```

but if I change the first line like this :

```
    g.addEdge(1, 0);
```

The DFS result is different because it is a directed graph. So what's the best way to implement the DFS as an undirected graphs, without the need to do two "searches" on the list? (I think  is the simplest way to do that ).
I found several ways to implement DFS to directed graphs but none to undirected graphs. Would be DFS just used to directed graphs?

What is the best book about graphs?

Regards

Antonio

Comment: I undertanding the adjacent matrix and iused to solve him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you are using is actually pretty good.
The easiest way to deal with this is to change the graph not implementation of DFS. So, you change the function addEdge as follows to add the edge in both directions:

```
void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w); // Add w to v’s list.
    adj[w].push_back(v);
}
```

Comment: @user3552769 Did I answer your question? If so, please accept/upvote the answer. If not, please comment.

Comment: Sorry for the log time to reply , but i was in holidays. I found the same solution in another site ! anyway your idea is very good :) thanks for solve my question